# Getting NPM error while starting server with ng serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am getting error :

`ERROR in /opt/NodeJS/FutureDMS/src/app/app.module.ts (5,9): Module '"/opt/NodeJS/FutureDMS/src/app/app.routing"' has no exported member 'APP_ROUTE'.`

I have used arrow function in loadChildren property for e.g :-

```
{
   path: 'dashboard',
   loadChildren: () => ExampleDashboardModule
}
```

I have the solution also. If i use

```
{
   path: 'dashboard',
   loadChildren: './example-dashboard/example-dashboard.module#ExampleDashboardModule'
}
```

instead of :

```
{
   path: 'dashboard',
   loadChildren: () => ExampleDashboardModule
}
```

then it will work fine. may be there is AOT compiler issue but i really want to use my routing with arrow function but not getting the proper solution please give some suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the complete app.routing and app.module file

Comment: You state a AOT issue. Does it actually work for you locally?

Comment: @Carsten actually i'm working on locally and it is not working. Whenever i try to compile my code it fails with that error that i've mentioned and after if i change something in my code and save it then it re-compile and it compile successfully.

Answer (score 2):

When using Lazy Loading (*loadChildren*), you need to specify the path to the module in *[path to file][#][module name]* - just like you discovered. You cannot get away from that unfortunately:

- Some information from [**OFFICIAL DOCS**](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration)
- Issue on Angular GitHub [**LINK**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16923)

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, but i just want to know there is no any possible way to do this with arror function ?

Comment: No, it's not possible atm. See the link I added in the answer

Comment: thanks, or may be i can use the `children`  property instead of `loadChildren` and import the routes of the another module and then i can use that routes as children routes am i right, @Fredrik ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use arrow function when using lazy loading. It should be a string.

**Why**?

When you do this

```
{
   path: 'dashboard',
   loadChildren: () => ExampleDashboardModule
}
```

you also do this ( not shown in your sample )

```
import {ExampleDashboardModule} from 'somewhere'
```

and you defeat the purpose of lazy loading because you added that import.

If it is just a string, you can just delete the line `import {ExampleDashboardModule} from 'somewhere'` and it will work just fine.